# square bracket and curly braces into fnmatch

Tags: python-3.x

I have input regression for wildcard support which is working fine using fnmatch. But some we also
get [](sqaure bracket also). can we handle such thing also using fnmatch

```
import fnmatch
b = ":F: abc pwr diff in wpr: pw[0] test"
fnmatch.fnmatch(b, ":F: abc pwr diff in wpr: pw[*")
```

Return True

```
fnmatch.fnmatch(b, ":F: abc pwr diff in wpr: pw[[0-9]]*")
```

Return false

I know I can handle this using regex but looking solution for fnmatch, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the individual brackets in brackets to create a pattern match on a single character:

```
fnmatch.fnmatch(b, ":F: abc pwr diff in wpr: pw[[][0-9][]]*")
```